# The /questions/{id}/timeline route isn't working.

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, timeline

I'm getting a response code 500 for the [/questions/{id}/timeline](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=questions/%7Bid%7D/timeline) route.  I've tried it in Firefox and by fetching a response in Java.

Example URL:  http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/59294/timeline

Comment: Confirmed, was just trying it in my project as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *should* be fixed now.

The underlying post timeline is [getting shaken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/54366/feedback-request-newer-timeline-question-view) up a little bit, so this method way experience some outages or changes in the immediate future.